# Filtering posts from yesterday, last week and last month doesn't work

Tags: python, django

I am using a simple form to filter posts based on yesterday, last week, last month and last year.

[image]

And this is the view, how I wanted it to be handled:

```
def search(request):
    queryset = Listing.objects.all().order_by('listing_date')

    # filter by date added
    list_date = request.GET.get('list_date')
    today = timezone.now()
    if list_date:
        if list_date == 'yesterday':
            yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)
            print(yesterday, 'yesterday')
            queryset = queryset.filter(listing_date__lt=yesterday)
            print(queryset) 
        elif list_date == 'lastweek':
            lastweek = today - timedelta(weeks=1)
            queryset = queryset.filter(listing_date__lt=lastweek)
        elif list_date == 'lastmonth':
            lastmonth = today - timedelta(days=30)
            queryset = queryset.filter(listing_date__lt=lastmonth)
        elif list_date == 'lastyear':
            lastyear = today - timedelta(days=365)
            queryset = queryset.filter(listing_date__lt=lastyear)

    context = {
        'listings': queryset,
    }

    return render(request, 'listing/listings.html', context)
```

and in model: `listing_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`. I printed yesterday and queryset above and it returns this in console:

```
2020-05-26 03:54:45.107533+00:00 yesterday 
<QuerySet []>
```

I filtered posts by yesterday, but why the queryset is empty, although I am sure posts were created yesterday?

Comment: For yesterday's records, you should query with date which is less than 2020-05-27 00:00:00.000000+00:00, currently its trying to find records which are less than 2020-05-26 **03:54:45.107533+00:00**. There might be records for yesterday but they could be created after 03:54:45 time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the following filters

- [date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#date)
- [week](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#week)
- [month](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#month)
- [year](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#year)

### Usage

1. yesterday

```
yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)
queryset = queryset.filter(listing_date__date=yesterday)
```

2. lastweek

```
lastweek = today - timedelta(weeks=1)
queryset = queryset.filter(listing_date__week=lastweek.isocalendar()[1])
```

3. lastmonth

```
lastmonth = today - timedelta(days=30)
queryset = queryset.filter(listing_date__month=lastmonth.month)
```

4. last year

```
lastyear = today - timedelta(days=365)
queryset = queryset.filter(listing_date__year=lastyear.year)
```

---

### Note

The python ***`timedelta(...)`*** is not much *accurate*, so I suggest using [**`relativedelta(...)`**](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) would be good for you.

Comment: Thank you sir, this answer is very helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

You are using the less then filter instead you should use less then or equal to filter

```
    if list_date == 'yesterday':
            yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)
            print(yesterday, 'yesterday')
            queryset = queryset.filter(listing_date__lte=yesterday)
            print(queryset)
```